# Domains sometimes fail to resolve over proxy

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, ssh, proxy

I don't know a lot about networking, so I'm not sure what to do next with this problem I'm having.
There is a machine which I can SSH into, call it `box`, which does not have access to the broader internet. I would like to give it tempory internet access, so as per [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116191/give-server-access-to-internet-via-client-connecting-by-ssh) I installed the `squid` proxy on my host machine, and ran `ssh -L 3129:localhost:3128 user@box`, and then `export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3129; export https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3129` on `box`, and now I can successfully `wget google.com`. Great!

However, running `ping google.com` gives:

```
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

What's up? How come `wget` can connect to `google.com`, but `ping` cannot? How could I change things so that the `ping` command works as well?

Comment: Hi, can you just use blocking rule, VLAN, etc.. to shape the traffic you want for that 'box' ? It's a lot easier to open the internet from the firewall side when it's needed for that host IMO.

Comment: "which does not have access to the broader internet. I would like to give it tempory internet access, so as per this answer I installed the squid" Squid is mostly for HTTP(S) traffic. Any other kind of traffic needs another type of gateway either at application level, like squid, or lower in the TCP/IP stack.

Comment: @yagmoth555 I'm not able to change firewall rules for this machine, but thank you

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Alright, so squid is not the right tool for this? Do you know of something better?

Comment: One of the current favored VPN solution is Wireguard. However, "There is a machine which I can SSH into, call it box, which does not have access to the broader internet." there may be reasons (aka policies) for this machine not to have access to Internet, specially in a business setting (the topic of this forum). So you may in fact better first ask with its network administrators to see if what you are attempting to do is first allowed per local policies, before trying how to do it (for which the relevant network/sys admins should be able to help you).

Comment: Thank you. The problem came up in a business setting, but this question was more about personal curiousity than serious application. It seems like networking is kind of compicated.